# Trying to replace value of a variable via powershell

Tags: powershell

I am trying to replace the value of a variable in parameters file using Replace(). This file which I am trying to edit accepts json format. But I am unable to do so. I am using this below script to do so. This only print the name of that particular field for which I am trying to replace a numeric value.

I tried this but it just displays the name of the variable which contains the old value I am trying to edit/replace.

```
if($Value -like "*xyz*")
    {
      $Value -replace '$OldValue', '$NewValue'
    }
else
   {
     Write-Host "$OldValue"
   }
```

Please provide a solution so that I can replace a numeric value of a particular variable for json file.

Comment: variables dont interpolate inside single quotes. Use double quotes instead.

Comment: Since you are talking about json, is `$Value` then not an **object** with a `.Name`  and a `.Value` property? How did you load the json file? Can you show us an example of this file?

Answer (score 0):

Good day Tanya

You should be able to use this:

```
if ($value -like *xyz*) {
   $value.replace($oldValue,$newValue)
} else {
   Write-Host $oldValue
```

Have a nice day

Comment: Hey thank you very much for your response but this is not working

Answer (score 0):

```
 $value ='tata'

Set-Variable -Name value -Value 'changed'
```

Comment: You can use this directly. Please let me know if it is helped you

Comment: And how can I set this value that is changed back to the file? I believe this is just setting the value to the variable and not replacing it.